# Counting number of rows related to an ID

Tags: mysql

I'm struggling to count the number of rows related to an id. The query returns correct data.

```
SELECT T.`payment`, T.`time_left`, T.`time_arrived`, T.`group_separator`, MD.`group_name`
FROM Transaction T
LEFT JOIN  Group G
ON T.`group_id` = G.`group_id`
LEFT JOIN division DI
ON G.`associated_group_id` = DI.`group_id`
LEFT JOIN meeting_data MD
ON G.`group_name` = MD.`group_name`
GROUP BY T.`time_left`;
```

Example of a dataset;

```
**payment**
paid
paid
not_paid
paid

**time_left**
2014-09-09 12:23:42
2014-09-09 12:24:14
2014-09-09 12:24:49
2014-09-10 19:04:12

**time_arrived**
2014-09-09 10:20:21
2014-09-09 10:21:16
2014-09-09 10:21:45
2014-09-09 15:35:06

**group_separator**   
25
25
25
26

**group_name**
Team Grey
Team Grey
Team Grey
Summer Blues
```

I'm now trying to count the number of rows that are a part of each `group_separator`.

So 25 will return a count of 3. 26 will return a count of 1.

I do a count(*) or count(distinct(group_separator)) and get a weird number of rows (I'm talking hundreds). There is about 77000 rows within the table mind.

Answer (score 0):

you are grouping by T.`time_left` so a count will give you a count of rows in each T.`time_left`. If you want a count by group_separator you would need to group by that instead.

Or have I misunderstood your question?

Answer (score 0):

First, do you really need `left outer join`s?  You are joining on fields that should have foreign key relationships and the `left outer join` is just saying "My data doesn't fit my data model".

Second, you are returning a lot of other information in the row that is more detailed that you would get at the group separator level.

Perhaps this query is what you really want:

```
SELECT T.`group_separator`, count(*) as NumGroups
FROM Transaction T JOIN 
     Group G
     ON T.`group_id` = G.`group_id` JOIN
     division DI
     ON G.`associated_group_id` = DI.`group_id` JOIN
     meeting_data MD
     ON G.`group_name` = MD.`group_name`
GROUP BY T.`group_separator`;
```

Actually, I look at this and I would be surprised if the other `join`s actually change the results at all.  You might just want:

```
SELECT T.`group_separator`, count(*) as NumGroups
FROM Transaction T
GROUP BY T.`group_separator`;
```